# Maximum number of connections allowed on an SQL Server running on a Windows Server 2000 machine

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, windows

I have developed a VBNET application that would require database connection (SQL Server 2005 Express) to a Windows Server 2000 PC. These applications will run in Windows XP and it is expected to be installed across at least 20 clients, all linked through LAN.

I would like to know if there are connection limits using Windows XPs or is the limit dependent on the server machine.

Also on a related note, are there limits for TCP/IP connections in the same case?

These are all so that I can decide whether to upgrade the client PCs to Windows 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: desktop versions of windows have all kinds of limits to prevent them from being used as servers. you're not likely to reach them by just having your app talking to your server. but... server 2000? that is beyond dated/obsolete.

Comment: XP is also unsupported/obsolete.

Comment: To expound on "obsolete": XP and Server 2000 are both "End of Life". That means that no new security patches are released, even when critical vulnerabilities are found. It's irresponsible to continue using them, and migrating to a new system should be job #1.

Comment: yea I know these machines are very much dead but I have no control over  these machines as they are under the company I'm working under. I will of course suggest an upgrade however i'll have to see how far they'll take my suggestion

Comment: Another point to further your quest to get the machines updated is that the hardware is likely to be near the end of its life too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection limits you're referring to only apply to *incoming* connections. For outgoing connections, you're fine. Additionally, the limits only apply to desktop operating systems like XP. Server 2000 does not have the same limitation.

In other words, this will work just fine... at least for a while.

However, the systems you're using are beyond obsolete... they are end of life. This means that no new patches are created or released for these systems, even when new critical vulnerabilities are discovered... and believe me, new vulnerabilities are discovered all the time. That makes these systems fundamentally insecure. It's irresponsible to continue using them, and only a matter of time until your network is hacked.

Comment: The system will only be run under a closed LAN network so unless they can hook up into one of our clients hacking isn't too big of an issue. I appreciate the advice however.

Comment: If these machines have any access to the internet at all, it's still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are connection limits but there are a few things you need to consider:

1. The database-access paradigm in .NET is to pool and use database connections on an as needed basis. This way database connections are not held unnecessarily
2. From #1 above follows that a single database server should be able to service lots of clients simultaneously if you write your code correctly
3. 20 clients is definitely within the realm of possibility - even for SQL Server Express which is not limited in terms of number client connections but is is limited by how much memory it can use and how many cores which indirectly limit the number of connections that it can handle. To the same point, there is a limit to how many TCP connections a Windows machine can handle but on a server OS the limitation will most likely come from resources (processing power and available memory) before you hit the arbitrary software limit of active TCP connections (which I believe is in the range of millions)
4. You are using seriously obsolete operating systems - these are no longer supported and you should move off of them as soon as possible!

Comment: Thanks alot for the info. However may I also ask regarding the 10 connection limit for WIndows XPs? Or are they solvable just by patching the sys file.

Almost all the client PCs are running on Windows XP and they'd have to upgrade all their hardware in order to support 7. I'll see if I can get them upgraded.